# C++ filling arrays by pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

having trouble creating an array of strings of size input by the user. I get the user input for size of the array however I can't pass this value to another function to create an array of strings. Any explanation as to what I am doing wrong here? I am passing by reference the value of the user input to my new function but I get error cannot convert `string` to `string*`

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


//function prototypes
void getSize(int &arraySize);
void getSpace(int arraySize, string *word);

   //Calls other functions otherwise does nothing
int main()
{ 
  int numStrings;
  string *words;

  getSize(numStrings);

  getSpace (numStrings, *words);

}//end main


// asks the user how many strings they want
void getSize(int &arraySize){
  cout << "How many strings do you want? ";
  cin >> arraySize;
}

// gets an array in the heap of the size requested by the user
void getSpace(int arraySize, string *word){
  word = new string [arraySize];
}
```

Comment: None of this pointer stuff is needed -- `std::vector<std::string> word(arraySize);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate it, however i am trying to learn how to better use pointers. Thanks for providing me with an easy way to do this however.

Comment: As a general advice: Don't use output parameters if you don't absolutely have to. getSize should just return an int and - if you want to stick to pointers- getSpace should return a pointer to the allocated array.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the elephant in the room, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector),

```
void getSpace(int arraySize, string *word);
```

specifies a function that takes an `int` and a pointer to a `string`. Inside the function you assign an array to the pointer of `string`s.

## But!

A pointer is a variable containing an address, and that address is being passed by value into the function. Inside `getSpace` `word` is a copy of the address provided by the caller. Both have the same value, point to the same place, but if you change where one is pointing, that change is not reflected in the other. Altering the value of `word` does nothing to change the original back in the calling function. You need to pass the pointer by reference to be able to update the pointer back in the caller.

You could define `getSpace` as

```
void getSpace(int arraySize, string * & word);
```

and call it

```
getSpace (numStrings, words);
```

But it would be easier to define it

```
string * getSpace(int arraySize);
```

and call it

```
words = getSpace (numStrings);
```

Save the hassle. Easier to read, too. By returning the pointer the function clearly gives the caller a pointer to a string. The previous version could be consuming a string, resulting in the uninitialized variable warning   Mikhail Genkin mentions in a comment to one of the other answers.

Remember to `delete[] words;` when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had similar issues before time to time, now I got what `* & word` means

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `word` by reference, rather than by value, in your `getSpace` function. i.e. change `*word` to `*&word`.

Just remember that if you plan on changing the location a pointer is pointing to, then you need to pass it by reference.

When you say `word = new string[arraySize]` in `getSpace`, what you are doing is setting word to point at the memory location containing the first element in the new string array.